# Convert codeigniter code to html

Tags: html, codeigniter

I have placed a codeigniter code and i want that code in html.Pls help me to do this.

```
<? echo anchor('login/signup', 'Create Account');?>
```

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: i want this code to be in html

Comment: `<a href="login/signup">Create Account</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want that code (which generates an anchor when the HTML page is rendered - look at your browser page source)

But what that CI URL helper translates to is:

```
<a href="login/signup">Create Account</a>
```

I can only assume you maybe want to add attributes to it and don't know how?
For example, you could add an `ID` and/or `class` like so:

```
<? echo anchor('login/signup', 'Create Account', 'id="some-id" class="some-class"');?>
```

Just ***make sure*** you're loading that 'helper' in your controller, or set it to autoload in the `config/autoload.php` file (which makes the most sense for this type of helper, as it'll likely be used site wide).

For more info on the CI URL Helper, visit here:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html